# Print and join statement in python

Tags: python, join, printing, sequence

I am newbie to python. I have a sequence and I am able to print it using `join` method and able to print the length of the sequence separately. I am not able to print both together. What I so far is:

```
>>> str = "-";
>>> seq = ("a", "b", "c"); 
>>> print str.join( seq );
   a-b-c
>>> print len(seq)
   3
```

I want to print both the `str.join(seq)` and `len(seq)` together in one line, with some `lines` like this (My desired output):

```
The join output is: a-b-c   The length is: 3
```

All of this in one line. Is it possible in `python`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
seq = ('a', 'b', 'c')
joined = '-'.join(seq)
print('The join output is:', joined, 'The length is:', len(seq))
```

or

```
print('The join output is: ' + joined + ' The length is: ' + str(len(seq)))
```

Comment: `len(joined) != len(str)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe what do you mean by this comparison?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yea sorry, a bit fuzzy in my head today, havn't eaten in two days :P Just assumed he wanted the length of the POST-joined string not the length of the sequence..

Comment: @user227666 the length of the sequence `seq = ('a', 'b', 'c')` is 3. The length of the string after the join `joined = 'a-b-c'` is 5. Which length you want depends on the circumstance, but it's important to note the difference.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, *don't use `str` as a variable name*. This is a built-in; using it as a variable name means you can't access it (e.g. to convert other items to strings).

Secondly, I would recommend string formatting here:

```
print "The join output is: {0}. The length is: {1}.".format("-".join(seq), 
                                                            len(seq))
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes I second @jonrsharpe *str* is buit-in and use should not use that name.

```
print " The join o/p is %s and The length is %s"%(s.join(seq),len(s.join(seq)))
```

Here your length is not 3 it will be 5. Since you have added 2 '-'. If you want to count excluding '-' then use line below.

```
print " The join o/p is %s and The length is %s"%(s.join(seq),len(s.join(seq).replace('-','')))
```